# Нет команд push и pull в редакторе Atom

Tags: atom

Версия 1.39, в документации написано, что реализована возможность загрузки обновлений в репозиторий на гитхабе. Репозиторий подключен, если возможность делать коммиты, но нет возможности загружать их в репозиторий, потому что просто нет необходимых кнопок. Может нужны какие-то дополнительне плагины?

как это выглядит у меня

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и как это должнно выглядеть согласно документации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хоть один коммит уже сделан? ``pull`` в некотором смысле есть - это кнопка ``fetch``. Но т.к. судя по всем проект еще пустой, что мерджить некуда (пулл это фетч + мердж), поэтому просто фетч.

Comment: на моем скрине один коммит уже сделан, по клику на фетч ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

Не являюсь каким-то экспертом, возможно неправильно понял вопрос, но у меня, чтобы произвести Пуш или Пулл нужно кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать нужный из выпадающей менюшки